# How to restrict merging permissions on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm pretty new to GitHub. I've made an organization, repository, and team. Is there a way that I can give someone on a team the ability to pull requests but not merge them to the main thread? I ultimately want to allow someone to make changes but also want to have the final decision of whether the change is kept to go through me. The read permission doesn't allow people to pull requests, and the write permission allows people to merge directly onto the main thread. Is there anything in between I could do, or any other methods I could use?

Comment: It sounds like maybe what you want to do is have them create their own forks of the project on GitHub, and then submit pull requests to your main project.

Comment: In this case, which permission would I give them?

Comment: In this case you would give them read-only permission. Permission to ask you to accept a pull request is implied in that.

Comment: Would I still be able to use the organization framework?

Comment: As long as it allows you to restrict permissions to read-only, then I don't see why not. Give it a try and see if it works!

Comment: I gave them read permission and they weren't allowed to make a pull request. They were using the desktop application and every time they would try to make a pull request they were alerted that they didn't have permission to do so.

Comment: That's unfortunate :/ Sorry for leading you down a false path. I think the general fork / pull request is the model you're after though. Maybe VonC's answer can help.

Answer (score -1):

You can ask make a [fork within organization repos](https://developer.github.com/changes/2012-11-27-forking-to-organizations/).
See also [organizations](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations):

> if a member of your organization forks one of your organization's repositories that fork will be considered part of the repository and can be added to teams.

You can give full access to team members on that fork, and they will make pull request from it.

You can remain the sole owner on the main original repo, and you will have the final decision, on which PR you are accepting (merging).

Comment: So the people would fork the repositories to their own accounts and we would stop using teams altogether?

Comment: @RohanKhajuria you should be able to assign a team to a fork which is a repo part of your organization.